# Creating a toolbar with buttons like Software Center

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

How do I create a toolbar with buttons that look like the ones in Software Center?

I've figured out out to set the style of the toolbar to Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR, but I want to set the buttons to look like page selectors instead of regular buttons.

I'm trying to create a bunch of buttons to switch between pages according to this specification: [Contributor Console](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributorConsole)

Thanks.

Comment: Quick tip: Software Center is also written in Python/GTK3. Head over to their Launchpad page, grab the source and have a look at how they do it.

Comment: I've looked through the code and can't figure out what it does to make the buttons look like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Global Pane in the code sets up the toolbar: `softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/globalpane.py`

While the ViewSwitcher class draws the buttons on the Global Pane:
`softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/viewswitcher.py`

Each button is added as a custom SectionSelector class composed of a custom cairo drawn Gtk.Image (SymbolicIcon class), a label and an optional drop down channel selector.  You should check out the viewswitcher.py file for more detail.

The SectionSelector class is in: `softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/buttons.py`
and is itself built from a custom class in that file.

Luckily, most of the code looks very reusable so you can probably copy and use them in your software.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer, I'll try it later.